# How to remove the undesired border of the GeoGraphics?

Tags: geography, geographics

I have created an image of Europe as below:-

```
g1 = (GeoPosition[{56, #}] & /@ Range[-10, 25, 5]);
g2 = (GeoPosition[{36, #}] & /@ Range[25, -10, -5]);
img = GeoGraphics[Polygon@Join[g1, g2], GeoProjection -> "CylindricalEqualArea"]
```

[image]

As you can see, the desired area in now in grey, and there's a border with lighter color there. How can I remove the border without using the trial-and-error approach of chopping `img` by pixels?

Many thanks!

Comment: See [`GeoRangePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoRangePadding.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `GeoRangePadding -> None`:

```
g1 = (GeoPosition[{56, #}] & /@ Range[-10, 25, 5]);
g2 = (GeoPosition[{36, #}] & /@ Range[25, -10, -5]);
img = GeoGraphics[Polygon@Join[g1, g2], 
  GeoProjection -> "CylindricalEqualArea", GeoRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

By default, `GeoGraphics` with `GeoRange -> Automatic` uses a range that encloses your content, then `GeoRangePadding` adds some extra space around it.  If you turn off the padding, you get just the area needed to include your content.