# How to avoid margin when combining ListDensityPlot and an Image?

Tags: plotting, image-processing, image, plot-themes

I have an image `img1` and some data with a density plot `plot1` to reflect the target position of the image. I tried to combine `img1` and `plot1` as below:-

```
targetPosition = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[123]; RandomReal[100, {35, 50}]];
img1 = ImageCrop[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Airport"}], {1000, 700}];
plot1 = ListDensityPlot[Exp@targetPosition, 
  AspectRatio -> ImageAspectRatio@img1, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img1], Axes -> False, Frame -> None];
ImageAdd[ImageMultiply[plot1, 0.6], ImageMultiply[img1, 0.4]]
```

[image]

As you can see, there's still a margin here. Thus the position will have errors due to the margin. How can I get rid of the margin?

Many thanks!

Comment: This problem is quite similar to [your previous one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175386/27951) from a few days ago, which was solved by using `GeoRangePadding -> None`...

Comment: Yes. Thus I was thinking the trick should be some Padding options at `ImageAdd`. I now realized that the Padding option should be set in `ListDensityPlot`. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PlotRangePadding >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotRangePadding.html)

> PlotRangePadding -> Automatic adds a total of 4% for PlotRange settings All, Full, and Automatic. For explicit settings, it adds no padding.

Adding `PlotRangePadding -> 0` to `ListDensityPlot` gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was stuck in the options of `ImageAdd`. Now it is solved!